# parsing vagrant file inside java

Tags: java, ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile, ruby-parser

I need to parse the configurations defined in a Vagrantfile written in Ruby and use the settings elsewhere in my java code. Tried exploring jRubyParser but din't come across any documentation that defines it's use.

Cloned the Vagrant repo locally, but browsing through the code does not help either as I don't have prior experience with Ruby. How would Vagrant be reading the configurations defined in the file ? Any inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrantfile is a regular Ruby script, i.e. it's meant to be interpreted by Ruby intepreter more than read as a configuration file.

To make things harder, some configuration options aren't declared as top level variables in Vagrantfile, but rather as properties of object in some function calls (like "config.vm.provider".

Depending on how complex your configuration is, I would consider just reading the file line by line and do regular expression matching to get variables I'd need. Not the most elegant solution, but probably way quicker too implement than alternatives.

Also, if your provider is always the same, say VirtualBox, maybe you could get some of your configuration from there. In that case, you would just need to read file located somewhere in "VirtualBox VMs" directory (on Mac, it's in "$HOME/VirtualBox VMs"). It's an XML file, so you could use one of the Java XML parsers to get what you need.

Comment: Can you give me a brief overview of how vagrant must be handling the Vagrantfile configurations internally ? I am not sure about how it would be mapping those settings to it's internal objects structures for further using them as inputs to providers like Virtualbox. Did you mean that this is something very Ruby like where Vagrant doesnt have much to worry about ? Can vagrant be doing anything with this Vagrantfile that would benefit me in anyway. Or otherwise I would surely go ahead and implement my own parser in Java. I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: The code would not be just constrained to Virtualbox, otherwise your input regarding the XML file would have worked great. However, that file would only be available if the machine(s) is/are already created in VBox. For other machines defined in VagrantFile but yet to be deployed on a provider, I would still have to go through the file contents instead :)

Comment: I don't know about the internals of Vagrant, unfortunately. Quick look suggest you should be looking at [loader.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb) and [vagrantfile.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb). Vagrant uses probably Ruby's blocks and procs to evaluate the config file.